# Align label in UITableViewCell on the right with Auto Layout

Tags: c#, ios, uitableview, autolayout

I want to use auto layout for may table view cell content. This worked so far. Now I want to align a `UILabel` on the right side of the table view. If I do this, it isn't aligned right. Instead it is completely on the left side. So it seems the width of the table view is not calculated when the constraint is applied. I tried two different approaches:

No. 1:

```
this.ContentView.AddConstraints (NSLayoutConstraint.FromVisualFormat ("H:[iNumberLabel]-|", (NSLayoutFormatOptions)0, null, viewsDictionary));
```

No. 2:

```
this.ContentView.AddConstraint (NSLayoutConstraint.Create (iNumberLabel, NSLayoutAttribute.Right, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, this.ContentView, NSLayoutAttribute.Right, 1, 0));
```

The constraints are added in `UpdateConstraints` in my table view cell subclass. The code is in C# but that doesn't matter. I would be glad if you could provide a solution.

Answer (score 1):

This format string: `"H:|-[iNumberLabel]-|"`

tells the system to pin the label to both sides of the cell with the default padding, so the label will be nearly the width of the cell. You should get rid of the spacing to the left side, if you want it right aligned,

```
"H:[iNumberLabel]-|"
```

I don't know why the second method didn't work. If that's the only horizontal constraint that you had, it should have worked.

Comment: Ohh thanks. I had it correct, but for testing purposes I used `H:|-[iNumberLabel]-|`. It's the only horizontal constraint. Hmm ...

Answer (score 1):

In addition to pinning it to the right side with:

`"H:[iNumberLabel]-|"`

You should also rightAlight the text with:

`cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;`

Comment: Thanks for your addition. That didn't helped.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Only working for iOS 8. Currently no solution for iOS 7.

This was the culprit

`this.ContentView.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;`

I had this set when I created and added my labels as subview. When this is turned off the width of the cell seems to not get correctly laid out. Perhaps one has to add some additional constraints for the `ContentView`, but I don't know which (content view to super view?).

Auto resizing mask has to be enabled for the content view.